# Using CSV arrays as an input to Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, csv, ascii

I have been presented with a csv file that is full of 100+ arrays that I need to run through my data analysis code but I am not sure how to read these arrays in Python. Each array is preceded with a line that includes only an integer that gives the number of rows in the array and ends with the line '1234567890' to be used as a line separator.

Here is a snippet of the csv file:

```
7,,,,,,,  
1,-199.117,-105.4,-4.525,227.5415,225.2925647,-0.0198891,-2.6547518
2,133.0423,55.4573,-48.4174,155.16,144.1380093,-0.322813,0.3949385
3,129.8405,-16.9527,-303.3192,331.0847,130.9425427,-1.5644458,-0.1298311
4,-73.6373,71.4677,151.517,183.9712,102.616198,1.1678785,2.3711453
5,41.2654,10.4196,30.3773,54.0915,42.5605604,0.6351541,0.2473322
6,-20.3159,-32.4484,62.4574,74.8581,38.2836056,1.2022641,-2.1301853
7,-13.2904,22.029,-28.2895,38.5096,25.7276422,-0.9386666,2.1136489  
1234567890,,,,,,,  
5,,,,,,,  
1,-136.0755,-204.2787,-48.2127,259.2592,245.4512762,-0.1881526,-2.158425
2,220.5184,46.9388,-113.6448,265.1745,225.4586784,-0.4581388,0.2097266
3,-45.3132,169.6283,-49.2729,188.9506,175.576326,-0.2669358,1.8318334
4,-40.7141,34.7414,25.5414,60.9535,53.5219844,0.4465159,2.4351851
5,15.3863,-49.6703,17.1692,56.7635,51.9988166,0.312235,-1.2704018  
1234567890,,,,,,,  
6,,,,,,,   
1,-19.3083,295.4128,191.8666,360.3712,296.0431267,0.5935079,1.6360639
2,-169.8708,-128.3904,-1.0052,215.4187,212.9323449,-0.0046663,-2.4943822
3,15.4505,-209.6656,-178.0715,279.4077,210.2341118,-0.7536439,-1.4972381
4,172.4142,13.0485,-63.7912,192.2842,172.9072576,-0.3447988,0.0755371
5,16.7456,24.8768,-46.5025,55.9188,29.9878358,-1.1933262,0.9783247
6,-8.911,4.1138,12.7751,17.7283,9.8147477,0.9089022,2.7090895  
1234567890,,,,,,,
```

I am certain I could import the array if the csv was just one big array but I am stumped when it comes to picking one array out of many. The data analysis needs to be run on the temporary array before it is replaced with the next array in the csv file.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) yet? It's very easy to use. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: The csv module is helpful to me if the csv file were just one big array, but I am not sure how to pick just one array, do the data analysis, and them move on the next array.

Comment: Uh, you just iterate over the object you get from `csv.reader(myfile)`. I fail to see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to parse the rows into separate arrays:

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('errors','w') as err: pass
with open('data','r') as f:
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(
            csv.reader(f),
            lambda row: row[0].startswith('1234567890')):
        if key: continue  # key is True means we've reach the end of an array
        group=list(group) # group is an iterator; we turn it into a list
        array=group[1:]   # everything but the first row is data
        arr_length=int(group[0][0]) # first row contains the length
        if arr_length != len(array): # sanity check
            with open('errors','a') as err:
                err.write('''\
Data file claims arr_length = {l}
{a}
{h}
'''.format(l=arr_length,a=str(list(array)),h='-'*80))
        print(array)
```

`itertools.groupby` returns an iterator. It loops through the rows in `csv.reader(f)`, and applies the `lambda` function to each row. The lambda function returns `True` when the row starts with `'1234567890'`. The return value (e.g. `True` or `False`) is called the `key`. The important point is that `itertools.groupby` collects together all contiguous rows that return the same key.

Comment: This seems to be working well! But is does run into an AssertionError once it gets to the sanity check.

`Traceback (most recent call last):`
  `File "CSV.py", line 12, in <module>`
    `assert arr_length == len(array) # sanity check`
`AssertionError`

Comment: That means the data file contains arrays where the reported array length does not equal the array data length. I've edited the script so such events will be logged in a file called `errors`. You can look in there after a run to investigate which pieces of data contain an error.

Comment: That's a very long way of writing `if arr_length != len(array): report_errors()` ... is there some hidden purpose for `try/except`?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a nicely formatted variable called "data" to work with.

```
import csv
rows = csv.reader(open('your_file.csv'))

data = []
temp = []

for row in rows:
    if '1234567890' in row:
        data.append(temp)
        temp = []
        continue
    else:
        temp.append(row)

if temp != []:
    data.append(temp)
```